# encryption method with numeric output

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I'm looking for a two way encryption method that will output only numbers approx 9 char length.
somthing like skip32, but I cannot use skip32.
I need it to be available to php and javascript. Thank you.

Comment: How about simply porting it to javascript?

Comment: I tried, but I have an issue with the function pack I found a pack for js from phpjs, but it does not give me the same result as in php for example the bytes 250,132,139,35 in php give me ת„‹# but in javascript I get ú# and that messes up the whole thing. I spent 5 hours on that.

Comment: You should explicitly encode/decode your string to bytes and back again. So use e.g. UTF-8 both for PHP and JavaScript. Encryption happens on bytes, not characters.